# What is the most expressive logic?

Tags: general-topology, logic, model-theory, foundations, proof-theory

What is the most expressive logic studied in the literature (in terms of expressing properties about a [structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)) in the sense of model theory)?

Many people talk about second-order logic, but third-order logic somehow does not play such a huge role. (Maybe one reason is that [second-order logic can simulate higher-order logic in some sense](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#4).) Can one also define $\omega$th-order logic? Can one define $\alpha$th-order logic for each ordinal $\alpha$?

Here are things a very expressive logic would be useful for:

1. Sometimes, people say "isormorphic structures have the same structural properties". But if one actually tries to formally write this down, one realizes that it is not that easy. The problem is with the notion of "property". Of course, one can take first-order logic and say "isomorphic structures satisfy the same first-order sentences". Okay, but many properties mathematicians are interested in go far beyond first-order logic. One can then say, "alright, then let's take second-order (or third-order, four-order) logic", but then one also has the problem that there is an even stronger logic. Probably there is always a stronger logic – but is there one that suffices for all practical purposes?
2. People talk about [topological properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property). Often they want to show that a property is topological. If there is a very expressive logic (that is capable of expressing many topological properties that occur in practice), one often could do this by just showing how to write down the property in the very expressive logic. (Note that [one needs third-order logic to formulate the axioms of a topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1052167/401895).) Is there, for example, a natural logic expressive enough to be able to express the topological property "... is metrizable"?

Comment: ZFC set theory is more expressive than $\alpha$-order logic for any ordinal $\alpha$, because in the language of ZFC we can already quantify over sets of all ranks, not just ones limited by $\alpha$.

Comment: @CarlMummert Thanks for your comment! I know a bit what you could mean. But in my question I talk about the expresiveness of a logic in terms of *expressing properties about a structure*. So if I have a sentence $\varphi$ of $\alpha$th-order logic and a structure $\mathcal A$, I can ask whether $\mathcal A \models \varphi$. But if I have a sentence $\varphi$ *in the language of ZFC* and a structure $\mathcal A$, I think one can't talk about a relation $\mathcal A \models \varphi$. Or is there some way of making it work? Would be very interesting.

Comment: I mean that for any formula $\phi$ in $\alpha$ order logic there is a formula $\psi(x)$ in ZFC so that $A \vDash \phi$ if and only if $\psi(A)$.  This is really nothing more than the fact that we can define $\vDash$ in ZFC.  But we can express more in ZFC than in any particular $\alpha$-order logic.

Comment: @CarlMummert Mhm, but isn't this (ZFC) a bit different than a logic? I am talking about a logic in the sense that for each signature $L$, we have a set of $L$-sentences, and for each such $L$-sentence $\varphi$ and each $L$-structure $A$, there is a relation $A\models \varphi$. $\alpha$th-order logic is a logic in this sense. But I doubt that ZFC can be considered a logic in this sense. This is why I don't understand why you are comparing ZFC with $\alpha$th-order logic in expresiveness.

Comment: As soon as you start looking at $\alpha$-order logic for large $\alpha$, you are basically just looking at fragments of set theory using a slightly different syntax. So, if the goal is more expressiveness, it might make more sense to just use set theory and skip the fragments.  If the issue is just a satisfaction predicate, we could write "$A \vDash^{st} \phi$" to mean that $\phi$ is a formula of the language of set theory with one free variable $X$, and $\phi(A)$ holds, and then we have a satisfaction predicate.  We're not using the ZFC axioms here, actually, just the language of set theory.

Comment: @CarlMummert "For any formula $\phi$ in $\alpha$ order logic there is a formula $\psi(x)$ in [the language of set theory] so that $A\models \phi$ if and only if $\psi(A)$." I think you also need to allow the ordinals $< \alpha$ to be used as parameters.

Comment: @user7280899 "Isn't this (ZFC) a bit different than a logic?" Yes: the language of set theory fails the isomorphism invariance property that I highlighted in my answer.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: yes, that seems right. But we also have to write down some kind of notation for $\alpha$ in the formulas of $\alpha$ order logic, so it seemed like a fair tradeoff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slogan "isomorphic structures have the same structural properties" (or more precisely, "isomorphic structures satisfy the same sentences") is perfectly true. I would even say that to call something a "logic", this is a crucial requirement. What you seem to be concerned with is the *converse* to this slogan: is there a logic such that if two structures satisfy the same sentences, then they must be isomorphic?

To address this question, let's try to clarify what a "logic" is. There are many ways to do this, but I'll concentrate on one option that seems relevant to your question. A logic $L$ for reasoning about structures in the sense of model theory (as in your question) will include a class $\mathcal{S}(L)$ of sentences, and every sentence $\varphi\in \mathcal{S}(L)$ will be true in some *isomorphism-closed* class $[\varphi]$ of models. Of course, a logic will also usually include formulas with free variables, which may be true or false of tuples from models, but let's just concentrate on the sentences, for simplicity.

Now we could take a turn for the abstract and define a "logic" to be a class $\mathcal{S}$ of "sentences" and a binary relation $\models$ on $(\text{Str}_L\times \mathcal{S})$, where $\text{Str}_L$ is the class of $L$-structures, such that for every $\varphi\in \mathcal{S}$, the class $[\varphi] = \{M\in \text{Str}_L\mid M\models \varphi\}$ is isomorphism-closed. Then we say a logic $(\mathcal{S},\models)$ is stronger than a logic $(\mathcal{S}',\models')$ if for every $\varphi'\in \mathcal{S}'$, there is some $\varphi\in \mathcal{S}$ such that $[\varphi'] = [\varphi]$. This is (more or less) the point of view of [abstract model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_model_theory).

From this point of view, there is an obvious strongest logic: The logic which has a "sentence" for every isomorphism-closed class of structures. Then for any structure $M$, there is a sentence $\varphi_M$ such that $M'\models \varphi_M\iff M'\cong M$, so if two structures satisfy the same sentences, then they're isomorphic. Of course, this is somewhat unsatisfying, since this logic has a proper class of "sentences"! In every language $L$, there is a proper class of $L$-structures up to isomorphism, and hence a proper class of isomorphism-closed classes of $L$-structures. So we can't expect to have any reasonable syntax for this logic.

To deal with this problem, we could make the further restriction that the class $\mathcal{S}$ of sentences must be a set. But then, as you suggested in the question, there will always be a stronger logic: For any logic $(\mathcal{S}, \models)$, there will be some pair of non-isomorphic models $M\not\cong M'$ which satisfy all the same sentences in $\mathcal{S}$. And we can add to $\mathcal{S}$ a new sentence which distinguishes $M$ and $M'$ (e.g. a sentence $\varphi_M$ such that $N\models \varphi_M\iff N\cong M$).

The point of all this is that the converse of the slogan is too much to hope for in general: There's no concrete logic such that if two structures satisfy the same sentences of that logic, then they are isomorphic. But if you're interested just in some restricted class of models, then there are indeed logics which "suffice for all practical purposes". For example, if two finite structures satisfy all the same first-order ($L_{\omega\omega}$) sentences, then they are isomorphic. And if two countable structures satisfy all the same sentences of the infinitary logic $L_{\omega_1\omega}$, then they are isomorphic (warning: this pattern doesn't continue to higher cardinalities, i.e. it's *not* true in general that if two structures of size $<\kappa$ satisfy the same sentences of $L_{\kappa\omega}$, then they're isomorphic).

For more information about the zoo of logics, abstract and otherwise, I recommend the book *Model-theoretic logics*, edited by Barwise and Feferman. It even has a section (Part E) on logics for topology and analysis, which is relevant to the second part of your question (note that topological spaces are *not* structures in the sense of classical model theory).

Comment: Alex, thank you very much for your extensive answer, I learned quite a bit from it! However, I think that there are some points in my question you didn't answer. For example, what are some very expressive logics studied in the literature? (Where the sentences are really finite strings of symbols rather than "pathological" logics such as the logic where the sentences are equivalence classes of structures -- though, of course, this is good to know for theoretical considerations.) Also, can one define $\omega$th-order logic? Can one define $\alpha$th-order logic for each ordinal $\alpha$?

Comment: I wonder what gave you the feeling that I am interested in the converse of "isomorphic structures have the same structural properties". Of course, this would be a natural question in this context, but I wasn't thinking of this when writing my question.

Comment: Thank you also for your literature "recommendation". Maybe this book answers the questions you did not answer. But if possible, it would be good to also have some pieces of the information here online. Thanks again, I hope you don't consider my critique to be ungrateful, because I am in fact very grateful for your answer!

Comment: 1. There are three main kinds logics studied in the literature which are more expressive than first-order logic: infinitary logics, higher-order logics, and logics with exotic quantifiers. You'll find many explicit examples in the book I recommended - these three kinds of logics correspond to parts C, D, and B, respectively. 2. Yes, it is possible to define $\alpha$th-order logic for each ordinal $\alpha$. But I'm not aware of any well-developed theory of such logics.

Comment: 3. Point 1 in your question is what made me think you're interested in the converse. But maybe I misunderstood the motivation. If you take for granted the statement "isomorphic structures have the same structural properties", and then you start expressing properties by sentences in various logics, and then you wonder if there's a strongest logic, the natural extension of this line of thinking is that you want a logic which can express all structural properties, i.e. one for which the theory of a structure determines it up to isomorphism.

Comment: 4. No, don't worry, you didn't come off as ungrateful at all! Your critique is well-taken, I only addressed one facet of your question.

Comment: Alex, thank you very much! I accepted now your answer, because I think together with the discussion in the comments, most aspects of my question are now answered in some way. Also, I looked into the book by Barwise and Feferman, it's exactly (or, at least, very close to) what I was looking for!